# React Fullcalendar - column header format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm trying to modify the column headers of a FullCalendar calendar on React, so I looked at the doc and I came across this:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/columnHeaderFormat

Only after a few unsuccessful attempts, I have the impression that this parameter is not implemented in the react version of fullCalendar (v5.3.0)... Would you have a solution to act on the columns format ? Or am I doing things wrong?

Here part of my code

```
<FullCalendar
   plugins={[timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
   initialView="timeGridWeek"
   headerToolbar={{
      left:'',
      center:'',
      right:''
   }}
   locale="fr"
   slotMinTime="07:00:00"
   slotMaxTime="20:00:00"
   height={640}
   selectable={true}
   columnHeaderFormat={{ weekday: 'long' }} // Problem here
   selectMirror={true}
   dayMaxEvents={true}
   select={handleDateClick}
   dateClick={handleDateClick}
/>
```

Comment: You're correct this option doesn't exist in v5

Comment: For v5 I think you should be looking here for equivalent functionality: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slot-render-hooks

Comment: In fact I succeeded using the "dayHeaderFormat" parameter by searching randomly among the available parameters... !

Answer (score 2):

**dayHeaderFormat**, as mentioned by Minos in the question commentaries, worked for me.

```
//package.json versions
"@fullcalendar/core": "^5.6.0",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.6.0",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.6.0",
"@fullcalendar/react": "^5.6.0",
"@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.6.0",


import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";

<FullCalendar
  plugins={[timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
  headerToolbar={{
    left: "",
    center: "",
    right: "",
  }}
  initialView="timeGridWeek"
  allDaySlot={false}
  initialDate={"2021-05-09T00:00:00"}
  editable={true}
  selectable={true}
  events={events}
  dateClick={(e) => {
    console.log("click: ", e);
  }}
  eventClick={(e) => {
    console.log("click: ", e);
  }}
  dayHeaderFormat={(param) => {
    console.log(param);
    return param.date.day.toString();
  }}
/>
```